# PHP extract all possible combinations from data

Tags: php, loops, recursion, iterator

I would like to extract all the possible variations of the data in the following array ($OriginalData) to how it is laid out in the 2nd array ($Variations).

In this instance, there are 3 questions but this figure is variable. Question 1 has 3 options, question 2 has 5 options and question 3 has 2 options.

I need to get an array of objects which contain every possible answer combination of the 3 questions.  In this case I believe there should be 30 possible combinations.  I have provided the expected output (for the first 3 combinations) in the $Variations array.

Any help greatly appreciated!

```
$OriginalData = array();
$OriginalData[] = (object) array(
    'ID'=>51,
    'Options'=>array(
        array('OptionID'=>27396,'Surcharge'=>50),
        array('OptionID'=>27397,'Surcharge'=>40),
        array('OptionID'=>27398,'Surcharge'=>45),
    )
);

$OriginalData[] = (object) array(
    'ID'=>52,
    'Options'=>array(
        array('OptionID'=>27383,'Surcharge'=>5),
        array('OptionID'=>27384,'Surcharge'=>5),
        array('OptionID'=>27385,'Surcharge'=>5),
        array('OptionID'=>27386,'Surcharge'=>5),
        array('OptionID'=>27387,'Surcharge'=>5),
    )
);

$OriginalData[] = (object) array(
    'ID'=>53,
    'Options'=>array(
        array('OptionID'=>27343,'Surcharge'=>12),
        array('OptionID'=>27344,'Surcharge'=>15),
    )
);

print_r($OriginalData);


$Variations[0]['Options'][51] = (object) array('OptionID'=>27396,'Surcharge'=>50);
$Variations[0]['Options'][52] = (object) array('OptionID'=>27383,'Surcharge'=>5);
$Variations[0]['Options'][53] = (object) array('OptionID'=>27343,'Surcharge'=>12);  
$Variations[0]['Summary'] = (object) array('TotalSurcharge'=>67);   

$Variations[1]['Options'][51] = (object) array('OptionID'=>27397,'Surcharge'=>40);
$Variations[1]['Options'][52] = (object) array('OptionID'=>27383,'Surcharge'=>5);
$Variations[1]['Options'][53] = (object) array('OptionID'=>27343,'Surcharge'=>12);  
$Variations[1]['Summary'] = (object) array('TotalSurcharge'=>57);   

$Variations[2]['Options'][51] = (object) array('OptionID'=>27398,'Surcharge'=>45);
$Variations[2]['Options'][52] = (object) array('OptionID'=>27383,'Surcharge'=>5);
$Variations[2]['Options'][53] = (object) array('OptionID'=>27343,'Surcharge'=>12);  
$Variations[2]['Summary'] = (object) array('TotalSurcharge'=>62);   

print_r($Variations);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
$OriginalData = array();
$OriginalData[] = (object) array(
    'ID' => 51,
    'Options' => array(
        array('OptionID' => 27396, 'Surcharge' => 50),
        array('OptionID' => 27397, 'Surcharge' => 40),
        array('OptionID' => 27398, 'Surcharge' => 45),
    )
);

$OriginalData[] = (object) array(
    'ID' => 52,
    'Options' => array(
        array('OptionID' => 27383, 'Surcharge' => 5),
        array('OptionID' => 27384, 'Surcharge' => 5),
        array('OptionID' => 27385, 'Surcharge' => 5),
        array('OptionID' => 27386, 'Surcharge' => 5),
        array('OptionID' => 27387, 'Surcharge' => 5),
    )
);

$OriginalData[] = (object) array(
    'ID' => 53,
    'Options' => array(
        array('OptionID' => 27343, 'Surcharge' => 12),
        array('OptionID' => 27344, 'Surcharge' => 15),
    )
);

$variations = array();
$counts = array();
$combinations = [[]];
$length = count($OriginalData);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $counts[] = range(0, count($OriginalData[$i]->Options) - 1);
}
for ($count = 0; $count < $length; $count++) {
    $tmp = [];
    foreach ($combinations as $v1) {
        foreach ($counts[$count] as $v2)
            $tmp[] = array_merge($v1, [$v2]);
    }
    $combinations = $tmp;
}
$x = 0;
foreach ($combinations as $c) {
    $totalsurcharge = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $Variations[$x]['Options'][$OriginalData[$i]->ID] = (object) $OriginalData[$i]->Options[$c[$i]];
        $totalsurcharge += $OriginalData[$i]->Options[$c[$i]]['Surcharge'];
    }
    $Variations[$x]['Summary'] = (object) array('TotalSurcharge' => $totalsurcharge);
    $x++;
}

var_dump($Variations);
```